# Closed Linear Operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T: X \longrightarrow Y$ be a linear operator, here X,Y are normed spaces. Then, $T$ is closed if, and only if, the conditions $ x_n \to 0;  \space T(x_n) \to  y$ imply $y=0$

If $T$ is closed, then the conditions $ x_n \to 0;  \space T(x_n) \to  y$ imply $T(0)=0=y$, by definition of closed operators. I need to prove the back.

Comment: If $x_n \to x$ and $Tx_n \to y$ then $(x_n - x) \to 0$ and $T(x_n - x) \to y - Tx$.

Comment: I understood!!! How I justify that x $\in D(T)?

Comment: From the first line in your question, I assumed that $D(T) = X$ so that this is automatic. If not, the result is incorrect. Actually the condition is equivalent to $T$ being closable for a general unbounded operator whose domain is not the whole space.

Comment: Thank's Rhys. :)